# Affix position not being recalculated on resize

Tags: javascript, resize, window-resize, affix

I want to make my navbar become affixed when you scroll and it reaches the top even when you resize the window.

The position at which it's triggered is not updating even though I set it to recalculate the values when I `$(window).resize()`. What's wrong?

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(window).resize ->

    windowHeight = $(window).height()
    navHeight = $('#navbar-affixable-wrapper > #navbar.affixable').outerHeight()
    windowMinusNavHeight = windowHeight - navHeight

    $('#navbar-affixable-wrapper > #navbar.affixable').affix
      offset: { top: windowMinusNavHeight }
```

Or in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $(window).resize(function() {
    var navHeight, windowHeight, windowMinusNavHeight;
    windowHeight = $(window).height();
    navHeight = $('#navbar-affixable-wrapper > #navbar.affixable').outerHeight();
    windowMinusNavHeight = windowHeight - navHeight;

    return $('#navbar-affixable-wrapper > #navbar.affixable').affix({
      offset: {
        top: windowMinusNavHeight
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you return the offset top value as a function?

For example:

```
$(function(){

   var $window = $( window );
   var $navbar = $('#navbar-affixable-wrapper > #navbar.affixable');

   $navbar.affix({
      offset: {
        top: function(){
           // Calculate offset top value
           return $window.height() - $navbar.outerHeight( true ); // I always pass true in there so margin is taken into consideration.
        }
      }
    })
});
```

You can checkout the [affix documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) on the Bootstrap website.

Comment: the trouble is with resizing.

I recalculate the values within the resize function, but it seems what i'm referencing are still the old cached dom with the old heights. How would i "refresh" the dom so that it accurately reflects the new heights upon resizing? If that can be done, then I don't see why the logic of setting the affix within the resize function wouldn't result in the intuitive behavior.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: i have a website, but maybe you have a fiddle that this working properly upon resizing? I haven't been able to get the top offset value to properly update when resizing in mine.